# Amnesia just closes after I select New Game

Tags: 64-bit, intel-graphics, games

I have a laptop with Intel GMA 4500M integrated graphics, 4GB of RAM and a 2.2GHz dual core processor with Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit. I recently bought the Humble Indie Bundle 5 and I was able to install and play LIMBO, Bastion and Sword and Sworcery, I haven't installed Psychonauts yet and I have installed but unfortunately cannot play Amnesia.

I choose the lowest possible settings but when I start a new game it just closes on me. Any suggestions?

Comment: I have installed bastion and amnesia by downloading the torrents and running the .sh files, not via the ubuntu software center.

Comment: Same happens to me, i have Nvidia and installed Amnesia through the software center

Answer (score 3):

I will copy and paste my answer to a similar question that was [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/149154/65969)

> I was able to get my Intel Sandy Bridge working.
>
> First you need to have mesa-utils installed
>
> you need need the s3tc library installed, it allows the texture
>   compression needed by mesa
>
> search for and install
>
> ```
> libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0
> ```
>
> in the Software Center.
>
> If you card can support it, the game will launch. There are several
>   quality selections in the launch window that comes up so you can try
>   low if medium doesn't work. Medium works for me, I haven't tried High
>   as Medium is very nice.
>
> I can tell you that apport seems to think that your gpu hangs so you
>   may get the "System error encountered" box popping up but I had no
>   hangs except when apport was gathering information and after I removed
>
> apport, apport-gtk, apport-symptoms
>
> I have been playing with no problems for the last 3-4 days. So if you
>   can get it working you may have to uninstall those progrmas or disable
>   apport to play without interruptions.
>
> If you tell the launch window for Amnesia to detect your card it will
>   tell you it's unsupported but as I said it is working fine on my
>   Intel.

If your video card will support Amnesia this fix should work.

Comment: I just did "sudo apt-get install libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0" and now it works perfectly ! thanks :D

Comment: glad I could help, I can only take credit for finding the page that told me how to do it. It was driving me crazy as well, esp. as the developer had a very similar game that would run fine on my computer.

Comment: it worked for me too!

Answer (score 1):

These steps WORKED! Thank you so much

1. Installing mesa-utils
2. Installing the s3tc library, which allows texture compression

I searched for and installed libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0 from the Ubuntu Software Centre

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded and installed the files in this youtube video: http://m.youtube.com/#/watch?v=9klAxeQsHlQ&desktop_uri=%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D9klAxeQsHlQ

Now I can play Amnesia on Ubuntu 12.10. 
2.2ghz dual core processor. 5gb ram. Intel GMA 4500M.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score -1):

Here is what a guy did to install the game:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RMq0BWMOdgc

Comment: A step by step guide with reference to the video if needed would be better than just an external link.