# How do I find a proprietary driver for the Intel graphics card I have?

Tags: drivers, dell, intel-graphics

I have an Intel corporation core processor integrated graphics controller (rev 18), and I am trying to get a proprietary driver for my graphics card so I can play Amnesia from the Humble Bundle.

I am a female that can easily follow directions but doesn't know much about Linux yet. If you give me precise directions, I will follow them so you can help me fix the problem. I would really appreciate it!

My laptop is a Dell n7010.

Additional info: I believe that it is the graphics card that is causing Amnesia to crash, but I am unsure. I have tried running it on the lowest possible settings, and it crashes after the first loading screen. :(

Also, I installed via the Ubuntu Software Center after purchasing the Humble Bundle. I have not tried the other games yet.

Comment: which version of ubuntu do you use?

perhaps updating your drivers helps (http://askubuntu.com/questions/124640/how-to-upgrade-intel-graphics-package/125197#125197)

Comment: I am currently following the terminal directions now. I use ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Can you provide us with more information about the crash you are experiencing, if possible? This information often can be found by running the affected program from the terminal and then copy-pasting the output as either a code block in your question or as a link to a paste at [pastebin.ubuntu.com](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/).

Comment: Related (possible duplicate?): http://askubuntu.com/q/146587/18612

Comment: I am so sorry, but can you show me how to run amnesia from terminal? I copied the entire file to my desktop. what code should I put in the terminal?

Comment: I have been keeping tabs on that askubuntu. The video doesn't really help as it is in spanish. I'm fairly certain the issue is with my graphics card, I'm just trying to figure out if there's a way around it by updating my drivers. It is an intel graphics card that isn't that great, but its managed to play other graphic-intensive games before (fallout). How do I run it from terminal so I can copy the crash code block? sudo amnesia doesn't seem to work. (I'm sorry I'm so new at this)

Comment: doing a quick reboot after following the terminal commands from MrMuretto's redirect. Update after I try amnesia again!

Comment: After following that post, amnesia still crashes. :(

Comment: open a terminal (either open the dash, type terminal and click on the icon or press Alt-F2 and type `gnome-terminal` and then hit enter) and type `amnesia` and hit enter. the game should start, but you'll have the terminal in the background outputting the errors.

Answer (score 3):

My laptop also uses Intel graphics (it is a Toshiba Satellite model), and it does not use proprietary graphics drivers. The reason for this is because the official Intel drivers for Intel graphics are themselves open-source; thus no proprietary drivers are available.

If you continue to have issues running Amnesia that appear to be graphics-related, then the issue is most likely with the game itself having a bug.

---

Relevant links:

- [Intel Download Center](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=13815&ProdId=3231&lang=eng&OSVersion=Linux%2a&DownloadType=Drivers)
- [Linux Graphics Drivers from Intel](http://intellinuxgraphics.org/)

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get my Intel Sandy Bridge working.

First you need to have mesa-utils installed

you need need the s3tc library installed, it allows the  texture compression needed by mesa

search for and install

```
libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0
```

in the Software Center.

If you card can support it, the game will launch.  There are several quality selections in the launch window that comes up so you can try low if medium doesn't work. Medium works for me, I haven't tried High as Medium is very nice.

I can tell you that apport seems to think that your gpu hangs so you may get the "System error encountered" box popping up but I had **no** hangs except when apport was gathering information and after I removed

```
apport, apport-gtk, apport-symptoms
```

I have been playing with no problems for the last 3-4 days.  So if you can get it working you may have to uninstall those progrmas or disable apport to play without interruptions.

As was said in another answer there are no propriety drivers for Intel, at least not that I know of either.

{edit}  If you tell the launch window for Amnesia to detect your card it will tell you it's unsupported but as I said it is working fine on my Intel.{edit}

Answer (score 0):

Intel drivers are in kernel by default, if you need hardware acceleration on movies via VLC the you need to install libva-intel-vaapi driver via USC. In case you want the very latest from git then add oibaf ppa at https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/graphics-drivers

On my system with the drivers from this ppa and sna enabled via xorg, it works quite well.

Answer (score -1):

Your proprietary drivers should be just a click and install through the Additional Drivers program.

Comment: The only driver it shows is the broadcom sta driver, no matter how many times I try to update it.

Comment: I use ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Broadcom is the proprietary driver for your wireless card, not the graphics. It won't be much use here.

Comment: I agree, just thought I'd let you know that no additional driver options show up.

Comment: Intel makes open source drivers--so you don't need to enable proprietary drivers for it, the OEM drivers are included in the kernel (well as long as you have a recent kernel).

Answer (score -1):

This guide will show you how to get new drivers via the GUI or in Terminal. Its from ubuntulinuxguide.com [Ubuntu Proprietary Drivers](http://www.ubuntulinuxguide.com/proprietarydrivers.htm)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.