# How to get intel graphics drivers for 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, graphics, intel

I did some looking around and it seems like there was, at one time, an intel-made graphics program for Ubuntu 14.04. But it seems that they have since started only supporting 14.10 (which is ridiculous, considering 14.04 is LTS), and I was wondering how I could get the old program that worked with 14.04, from a website download or whatever. I have a 2012 MacBook Pro with an Intel HD 4000, if that helps in the matter. And of course if there are other ways to get drivers for this particular card-I remember being able to do it straight through the Additional Drivers program back when I had an Nvidia laptop-that would be great too. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See this post at Intel's forums for explanation:  https://01.org/comment/2141#comment-2141

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. What a shame. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

There are no proprietary drivers for Intel (which is the reason you use another interface for installing the nvidia drivers - they're provided as binary blobs. In case you want to have more up-to-date drivers for your intel graphics card, you can add this ppa:

```
https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/ubuntu/x-updates
```

but I would not recommend it since it could lead to instabilities.

See also: [How do I find a proprietary driver for the Intel graphics card I have?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149154/how-do-i-find-a-proprietary-driver-for-the-intel-graphics-card-i-have)